# Unity3d: Rotate a gameobject towards forward vector of another gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, rotation, quaternions

```
        BackCube.position = cameraEye.position - cameraEye.forward * 2;

        float back = cameraEye.position.z - 2f;
        BackCube.position = new Vector3(BackCube.position.x, BackCube.position.y, back);

        var lookPosBack = cameraEye.position - BackCube.position;
        lookPosBack.y = 0;
        var rotationBack = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookPosBack);
        BackCube.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(BackCube.rotation, rotationBack, 1);
```

So, I want the my `BackCube` to rotate towards the forward vector of `cameraEye`. The code above looks at the `cameraEye`, but not towards the forward vector of `cameraEye`. I want the forward vectors of both pointing at each other being 2 units apart from each other. I have control only over the `BackCube`

Comment: Is BackCube a gameobject, a transform, or something else ? You have `BackCube.transform` and `BackCube.position` in your code so it is hard to tell. How about cameraEye?

Comment: I'm sorry! Fixed it! Both are `Transform`

Comment: Also, how far along the cameraEye's forward direction do you want to look? Exactly 1 world unit?

Comment: @Ruzihm Two units

Comment: @Ruzihm That ain't working!

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding this question. Is `BackCube` successfully positioned where you want it to be positioned with `BackCube.position = new Vector3(BackCube.position.x, BackCube.position.y, back);`? When you're talking about the position of these forward vectors, are you talking about the position of the tips of the forward handles on the [transform gizmos](https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/TransformGizmo35.png)?

Comment: If you could arrange some examples of outcomes you would want using the scene editor and attach some screenshots in the question that would help clear things up.

Comment: Your explenation is a bit confusing looking at your code ... what I understand you want the cube being placed like opposide to the `cameraEye` both having their forward pointing at each other ... then why do you set the cube `camerEye.forward * 2f` **behind** the cameraEye position instead of in front?

Comment: I would simply use `BackCube.position = cameraEye.position + cameraEye.forward * 2; BackCube.LookAt(cameraEye);` than they would be 2 Units apart and looking at each other ....

Comment: @MrRobot9 did you find an answer to your question here?

Comment: @Ruzihm I'm sorry! yeah, I got the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked!

```
Vector3 direction = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(cameraEye.forward, Vector3.up);


BackCube.transform.position = cameraEye.position - direction.normalized * 2;


var lookPosBack = cameraEye.position - BackCube.position;
lookPosBack.y = 0;
var rotationBack = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookPosBack);
BackCube.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(BackCube.rotation, rotationBack, 1);
```